# Late 2015 iMac won't wake from sleep - black display

Tags: macos, mac, sleep, osx-el-capitan

I just got hired to help run a lab of fifteen late 2015 iMacs running El Capitan. They were all reimaged this summer, and have a fusion drive setup to work with Deep Freeze.

Four of these iMacs will not wake up from sleep; or, more appropriately, the Mac will wake up, but the screen stays black. This happens both if the Mac puts itself to sleep or if I manually put it to sleep via the Apple menu. They don't respond to the keyboard/mouse/power button (regardless of USB port), but I can ssh into them and screen share into them as well. If I start a YouTube video while screen sharing, audio will play out of the speakers of the "sleeping" iMac. So it seems like it's just the screen.

I've tried doing `autopoweroff = 0` in `pmset` (`standby` and `hibernatemode` are already off as well), resetting SMC, resetting NVRAM, booting in Safe Mode, resetting and running diagnostics.

For logs right around the time I set it to sleep: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b6dab445e3f0cef947384c01e4ef4ea

Any ideas are appreciated! I haven't tried reinstalling the OS yet, but any ideas before that point would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help anyone else encountering this issue: it may be Deep Freeze-related. After thawing the drive, authorizing necessary programs, and freezing the drive, all four computers responded normally when waking from sleep (i.e., the display would show as it should have).

Answer (score 0):

Try and boot into single user mode. Power off, back on then hold `CMD + S`

If the menu doesn't come up still, again it's the screen as you said. If single user mode appears, try a filesystem check. Type `fsck -yf` to do that. If you have a problem, it will tell you. Or, better, if you can do it whilst in SSH then see if you can. Maybe permissions will get in the way - I don't know how you have it setup.

Talking of SSH, try this command to check it's status:

`sudo systemsetup -getcomputersleep` - If a number prints back, it represemts the number in idle minutes to determine when the sleep occurs.

Next try `caffeinate -u` - this simulates user activity via SSH or Terminal.

Comment: The black screen issue doesn't occur when it's powering on - just when it's waking from sleep. `fsck -yf` returned saying the filesystem was ok, so that's not the issue. :/ The computer's set to sleep after 10 minutes, but this happens if I manually put it to sleep as well. (edited original post to add that)

Comment: Did you try put it to sleep then use the `caffeinate -u` command?

Comment: Yes, both via ssh and through screen sharing. If I screen share as a black-screened Mac, I can wake it up and interact with it normally through the remote window. The remote view of the screen is as if the screen woke up. If I play music, it will play through the speakers of the black-screened Mac; I can open programs remotely, and if they play sounds, I'll hear them. I can tell the computer to restart, and it will. But no matter what I do, the physical screen of the iMac I'm remotely viewing remains black.

Comment: Have you tried PRAM resets?

Comment: Yeah, I did an NVRAM reset, which is apparently the same thing? Next thing to try is booting the computer with DeepFreeze thawed...

Comment: Try an SMC Reset - look [here](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3603)